# Multiple XML format from SQL Server single table

Tags: sql-server, xml

```
SELECT 
    consent_type, state_code,
    suburb, sex_code, postcode, 
    CarerPrimary, CarerResidence, CarerRelationship,
    service_type_outlet_codeno,
    last_service_date, service_hours,
    to_date, from_date
FROM 
    TABLEX
```

How can I get the following XML format from this single table? Most confusing is  `CarerPrimary`, `CarerResidence`, `CarerRelationship` part. This table contains information of multiple clients, so `service_user` part would appear once for each client. Thanks.

```
<agency>
    <service_user consent_type="1" state_code="2" suburb="Croydon" sex_code="1" postcode="3136">
        <service_user_response value="1" question_fieldname="CarerPrimary"/>
        <service_user_response value="1" question_fieldname="CarerResidence"/>
        <service_user_response value="9" question_fieldname="CarerRelationship"/>
        <service_user_outlet service_type_outlet_codeno="8376784"  last_service_date="02/9/2016" >
            <service_hours service_hours="240" to_date="15/8/2016" from_date="09/8/2016"/>
            <service_hours service_hours="90" to_date="02/9/2016" from_date="02/9/2016"/>
        </service_user_outlet>
    </service_user>
    <service_user .... >
    </service_user>
</agency>
```

New Code,

```
SELECT PostalCode AS [@Postcode]
      ,IIF (HC.HasCarer = 'true', 'Y', 'N') as [@has_carer_type]
      ,convert(date, [BirthDate], 111) AS [@BirthDate]
      ,'N' as [@birth_date_est_ind]
      ,IIF (new_gender = 6, 3, new_gender) AS [@sex_code]
      --SLK
      ,City AS [@Suburb]
      ,DEX.[dbo].[CRM2DEX]('State',[new_Address1State], 0) AS [@StateCode]
      ,'Y' as [@consent_type]

      --,CONCAT ([FirstName], ' ' + [MiddleName]) AS GivenName
   --   ,[LastName] AS FamilyName
   --   ,cb.new_ClientID AS ClientId

      /********service_user_response*******/
      ,HC.CarerPrimary AS [service_user_response/@value]
      ,'CarerPrimary' AS [service_user_response/@question_fieldname]
      ,HC.CarerResidence AS [service_user_response/@value]
      ,'CarerResidence' AS [service_user_response/@question_fieldname]
      ,dex.dbo.CRM2QDC('Relationship', default, HC.new_Relationship) AS [service_user_response/@value]
      ,'CarerRelationship' AS [service_user_response/@question_fieldname]
      --,IIF (new_CarerAgeGroup IS NULL, 99, new_CarerAgeGroup) AS CarerAgeGroup
      ,IIF (new_indigenoustatus = 9, NULL, new_indigenoustatus) AS [service_user_response/@value]
      ,'IndigenousStatus' AS [service_user_response/@question_fieldname]
      ,COALESCE (Country.[new_Code], '0003') AS [service_user_response/@value]
      ,'BirthCountry' AS [service_user_response/@question_fieldname]
      ,COALESCE (Lang.[new_Code], '0002') AS [service_user_response/@value]
      ,'Language' AS [service_user_response/@question_fieldname]
      ,new_interpreter AS [service_user_response/@value]
      ,'InterpreterServices' AS [service_user_response/@question_fieldname]
      ,new_communicationmethod AS [service_user_response/@value]
      ,'CommunicationMethod' AS [service_user_response/@question_fieldname]
      ,IIF (cb.new_livingarrangements = 9, 99, cb.new_livingarrangements) AS [service_user_response/@value]
      ,'LivingArrangements' AS [service_user_response/@question_fieldname]
      ,cb.new_residentialsetting AS [service_user_response/@value]
      ,'ResidentialSetting' AS [service_user_response/@question_fieldname]
      ,new_employmentstatus AS [service_user_response/@value]
      ,'LabourForceStatus' AS  [service_user_response/@question_fieldname]
      ,IIF (new_primaryincomesource = 7, 97, new_primaryincomesource) AS [service_user_response/@value]
      ,'IncomeSource' AS  [service_user_response/@question_fieldname]
      --,(SELECT IIF (Disability IS NULL, 'false', 'true') from HasDisablity where ClientID = CB.ContactId) AS HasDisabilities

      --,IIF (new_client is NULL, NULL, (select coalesce (new_name, null) FROM Health AS D where D.new_contact = CB.ContactId for xml path ('DisabilityCode'), type)) AS Disabilities
      --,(SELECT IIF (new_name IS NULL, NULL, (select H2.new_name from Health AS H2 where H2.new_contact = CB.ContactId
      --  for xml path ('DisabilityCode'), type)) FROM Health AS D where D.new_contact = CB.ContactId) AS Disabilities
--    ,DEX.[dbo].[CRM2DEX]('AccommodationType',C.new_residentialsetting, 0) AS AccommodationTypeCode
--    ,DEX.[dbo].[CRM2DEX]('DVACardStatus',[new_DVAentitlement], 0) AS DVACardStatusCode
      --,COALESCE (HasCarer, 'false') AS HasCarer 





--    ,DEX.[dbo].[CRM2DEX]('HouseholdComposition', C.new_livingarrangements, 0) AS HouseholdCompositionCode

  FROM [FOCUSCRM_MSCRM].[dbo].[ContactBase] AS CB
  INNER JOIN 
      (SELECT [ParentId]
             ,[Line1]
             ,[Line2]
             ,[City]
             ,[PostalCode]
      FROM [FOCUSCRM_MSCRM].[dbo].[CustomerAddressBase]
      WHERE addressNumber = 1 ) AS A ON CB.ContactId = A.ParentId

  LEFT OUTER JOIN 
      (SELECT [new_countryId]
             ,[new_name]
             ,[new_Code]
      FROM [FOCUSCRM_MSCRM].[dbo].[new_countryBase]) AS Country ON CB.new_CountryofBirth = Country.new_countryId

  LEFT OUTER JOIN 
      (SELECT [new_languageId]
             ,[new_name]
             ,[new_Code]
      FROM [FOCUSCRM_MSCRM].[dbo].[new_languageBase]) AS Lang ON CB.new_PreferredLanguage = Lang.new_languageId


  LEFT OUTER JOIN 
      (SELECT new_ClientName, new_livingarrangements, new_residentialsetting
        FROM (
        SELECT [new_ClientName]
        ,row_number() over (Partition by new_ClientName ORDER BY ModifiedOn DESC) AS R
        ,new_AssessmentDate 
        ,new_livingarrangements
        ,new_residentialsetting

        FROM [FOCUSCRM_MSCRM].[dbo].[new_assessmentBase] AS AB1
        WHERE statecode = 0 
          ) AS T1 

      WHERE R = 1) AS C ON CB.ContactId = C.new_ClientName

  LEFT OUTER JOIN HasCarer AS HC ON HC.new_clientname = cb.contactID

      WHERE CB.new_clientID IN (SELECT DISTINCT new_clientID from TS)
  and statecode = 0

  --) AS T GROUP BY ClientID having count(ClientId)>1 

 FOR XML PATH('service_user'),ROOT('agency');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without sample data it is a blind flight, but you might try something like this:

```
SELECT 
    consent_type AS [@constent_type]
  , state_code AS [@state_code]
  , suburb AS [@suburb]
  , sex_code AS [@sex_code]
  , postcode AS [@postcode]
  , CarerPrimary AS [service_user_response/@value]
  ,'CarerPrimary' AS [service_user_response/@question_fieldname]
  , CarerResidence AS [service_user_response/@value]
  ,'CarerResidence' AS [service_user_response/@question_fieldname]
  , CarerRelationship AS [service_user_response/@value]
  ,'CarerRelationship' AS [service_user_response/@question_fieldname]
  , service_type_outlet_codeno AS [service_user_outlet/@service_type_outlet_codeno]
  , last_service_date AS [service_user_outlet/@last_service_date]
  , service_hours AS [service_user_outlet/service_hours/@service_hours]
  , to_date AS [service_user_outlet/service_hours/@to_date]
  , from_date AS [service_user_outlet/service_hours/@from_date]
FROM 
    TABLEX
FOR XML PATH('service_user'),ROOT('agency');
```

`FOR XML PATH` allows to define the `XPath` as column alias. attributes are marked with a `@` sign.

The `service_hours` in your example look as if they were `1:n`, but the query does not look as such.

Comment: Thanks @Shnugo. You are right about service_hours. It is 1:n. Please have a look at my new query which giving me error. The joins are some tables and some CTE. Column name 'service_user_response/@value' is repeated. The same attribute cannot be generated more than once on the same XML tag.

Comment: @MohammedS Please try to reduce the code to the needed minimum... If the question is, how to create a nested `1:n`-related sub-node, just add a `(SELECT ...   FROM ... WHERE ... FOR XML PATH('xyz'),TYPE) AS [*]` in the appropriate place. The sub-select must use the `WHERE` clause to filter the fitting rows. And please avoid chameleon questions!

Comment: Thanks @Shnugo. Sub-node is not the issue. My issue was how to represent value and question_fieldname' from columns. I tried your code, but it is complaining as "Column name 'service_user_response/@value' is repeated. The same attribute cannot be generated more than once on the same XML tag." How to fix this problem?

Comment: @MohammedS Sure! I should have seen this, but without a chance to test this code, it's a blind flight... Just place `,''` (comma + empty string) after each `@question_fieldname]`. This will tell the engine to close the current element and start a new one.